# Was I wrong was my answer bad?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting

I posted this ([python how to rerun program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686553/python-how-to-rerun-program/29686703?noredirect=1#comment47510721_29686703)) and there's nothing that bugs me more than an unexplained down vote. Sometimes I feel like since I have lower reputation my responses are shrugged off as insignificant. Was I wrong?

The worst part is almost identical code received an up vote that was posted later probably just because of reputation.

Comment: the reason/downvoter is right there in the comments.

Comment: yes did you see my response?

Comment: The downvoting user may not have seen the other answer (as it came in later). Sometimes life just isn't fair...

Comment: Still, that has nothing to do with your reputation. Someone didnt understand your answer, thats a different story.

Comment: Words to live by. It makes me mad though gaining a reputation is something I really want to do. I don't know why but there's just something so rewarding about it and It's hard to get credit on that site with a lower rep.

Comment: @JGerulskis _"and It's hard to get credit on that site with a lower rep"_ No, it's not so much matter of having rep (though I've been reading comments today we should introduce measures like _milliSkkets_), but how to write good questions or answers. Usually lower rep users have less experience with these policies, thus their questions/answers are more down- or close-voted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)!

> *"The worst part is almost identical code received an up vote that was posted later probably just because of reputation."*

In general:

> Life isn't fair, and we're not living at a *pony farm*.

---

In particular:

> *"Sometimes I feel like since I have lower reputation my responses are shrugged off as insignificant."*

That's just an unproved perception, the more likely reason is your lack of experience with the SO site, and the policies setup here.

---

And finally:

> Money makes money (and again life isn't fair)

Voting here is truly secret. You don't need to disclose your reasons, and you just do it as soon [you have gained enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Downvoted, because "Life isn't fair, and we're not living at a pony farm". Seriously, sometimes posts I see on Meta feel like Nazi Germany.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it was *wrong*, per-se.  Your code will work just fine.

However, someone may have taken a dislike to the repeated declaration of the variable, and the avoidance of the `while True: break` idiom when you're accomplishing the same thing with similar syntax.

I didn't downvote (or know this answer existed until this question), but those are a couple of reasons why I think someone *might* downvote you.

That said, voting is anonymous and highly subjective - in *general*, you have people upvoting content that they believe to be of value.  Someone didn't think your answer was as good as another very similar one, and while that sucks, there's not much anyone can do except attempt to refine their answer.

If you think it'll stand up just fine against criticism though, then I'd let it be and not let the downvote bother you too much.